# Need tutorial on C# windows form application with serialization and de-serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, desktop-application

Please provide me the link if there is any tutorial on c-sharp desktop application which based on data serialization and de-serialization.

Comment: try searching the internet; it's really great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here you go](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file

http://dotnetperls.com/serialize-list

Serialization is not contingent on windows vs web app.